# Insert multiple rows into different tables

Tags: mysql

I want to insert multiple rows into different tables in my database. The statements are paired, where the second relies on data (specifically `LAST_INSERT_ID()`) from the first statement.

This code works, but I wonder if it can be done in a better way? 
Is there a way to have it all in one single query?

```
<?php

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_terms (term_id, name, slug, term_group)
VALUES ('', 'Test 1', 'test-1', '0')
");

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_term_taxonomy (term_taxonomy_id, term_id, taxonomy, description, parent, count)
VALUES ('', LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'mycustomfield', 'Descripton 1', '0', '0')
");

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_terms (term_id, name, slug, term_group)
VALUES ('', 'Test 2', 'test-2', '0')
");

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_term_taxonomy (term_taxonomy_id, term_id, taxonomy, description, parent, count)
VALUES ('', LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'mycustomfield', 'Descripton 2', '0', '0')
");

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_terms (term_id, name, slug, term_group)
VALUES ('', 'Test 3', 'test-3', '0')
");

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_term_taxonomy (term_taxonomy_id, term_id, taxonomy, description, parent, count)
VALUES ('', LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'mycustomfield', 'Descripton 3', '0', '0')
");

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_terms (term_id, name, slug, term_group)
VALUES ('', 'Test 4', 'test-4', '0')
");

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_term_taxonomy (term_taxonomy_id, term_id, taxonomy, description, parent, count)
VALUES ('', LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'mycustomfield', 'Descripton 4', '0', '0')
");

?>
```

Comment: You'd better add some error handling to those queries - they're interdependent (since you're using last_insert_id() and foreign keys). If one fails, the queries that come after it will fail as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a thing to reduce the call of `mysql_query`, Yes, There is a way but you have to use the `mysqli` for this.

The [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) can execute the multiple queries in once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Will look in to it.

Answer (score 0):

You also can create an INSERT trigger -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_wp_terms_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON wp_terms
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO wp_term_taxonomy(term_taxonomy_id, term_id, taxonomy, description, parent, count)
    VALUES ('', NEW.term_id, 'mycustomfield', CONCAT('Descripton ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.name, ' ', '-1')), '0', '0');
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then just add new rows into the wp_terms table using one bulk [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) statement -

```
INSERT INTO wp_terms (term_id, name, slug, term_group) VALUES
  ('', 'Test 1', 'test-1', '0'),
  ('', 'Test 2', 'test-2', '0'),
  ('', 'Test 3', 'test-3', '0'),
  ('', 'Test 4', 'test-4', '0');
```

Comment: Just to share.. this would work if the data to be inserted in `wp_term_taxonomy` is always constant, except for the `term_id` column.. The moment the data for this table changes, you'll just have to modify the trigger..

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using a stored procedure would be one of the `best ways` to do it:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertWpTermAndTaxonomy`
    ( IN paramWPT_id <<PlaceTheRightDataTypeHere>>
    , IN paramWPT_name <<PlaceTheRightDataTypeHere>>
    , IN paramWPT_slug <<PlaceTheRightDataTypeHere>>
    , IN paramWPT_termgroup <<PlaceTheRightDataTypeHere>>
    , IN paramWPTX_id <<PlaceTheRightDataTypeHere>>
    , IN paramWPTX_taxonomy <<PlaceTheRightDataTypeHere>>
    , IN paramWPTX_description <<PlaceTheRightDataTypeHere>>
    , IN paramWPTX_parent <<PlaceTheRightDataTypeHere>>
    , IN paramWPTX_count <<PlaceTheRightDataTypeHere>>
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO wp_terms (term_id, name, slug, term_group)
    VALUES (paramWPT_id, paramWPT_name, paramWPT_slug, paramWPT_termgroup)

    INSERT INTO wp_term_taxonomy (term_taxonomy_id, term_id, taxonomy, description, parent, count)
    VALUES (paramWPTX_id, LAST_INSERT_ID(), paramWPTX_taxonomy, paramWPTX_description, paramWPTX_parent, paramWPTX_count)
END
```

Then use code like this (though I choose PDO over MYSQL or MYSQLI):

```
# using an array which you can populate to contain all the 
# necessary parameters... 
$term_and_taxonomy_array_values = array('', 'Test 4', 'test-4', '0', '', 'mycustomfield', 'Descripton 4', '0', '0');

$sql = 'CALL InsertWpTermAndTaxonomy (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach($term_and_taxonomy_array_values as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->bindValue($key + 1, $value);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Hope you can look into PDO, but mysqli should be able to do this as well. I coded the procedure so that it can be flexible enough to take whatever acceptable parameters for both tables, even though it seemed like you have constant `0`s and `''`s

If you want to further make this dynamic, say for example you can build your array of parameter arrays, then you'll just need one more `foreach` to wrap it up...

Answer (score 0):

1. add an additional column to wp_terms, you can name the column as `session_key`, this is to store an unique value for each insertion, an example of unique value can be current timestamp concat with some WP session value
2. upon insertion, assign the `session_key` to an unique value and included into insert statement
3. combine all the insert into wp_terms into single `insert ... values (...,session_key), (..., $session_key)`
4. factor in error handling
5. after you have insert successfully, you can make use on the unique value you have created at step 2 to `insert into wp_term_taxonomy select ... where session_key = $session_key`

with this small trick, possibilities hitting an error is quite minimum